# Find the minimal polynomial for a root over the rationals

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Find the minimal polynomial over $Q$ of the root $(\sqrt[2]{3})/(1+\sqrt[3]{2})$. I'm new to field theory so please help!

(I'm new to the platform so excuse my sloppy notation)
So far, I set a= $(\sqrt[2]{3})/(1+\sqrt[3]{2})$, and by squaring both sides, I got $a^2+2^{4/3}a^2+2^{2/3}a^2=3$. I tried manipulating this expression quite a bit, but I can't seem to be able to get rid of the fractional exponents. I tried isolating the cubic root to one side and cubing both sides first as well and no luck. Am I supposed to be using other principles?

Comment: what have you tried? put it in the question

Comment: The question is clear, but you need to show some type of effort of explanation or trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $a = \frac{3^{1/2}}{1+2^{1/3}}$, as is already pointed out in the OP's question, squaring gives
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
a^2 = \frac{3}{1+2.2^{1/3} +2^{2/3}} \implies a^2(1+2^{2/3}+2^{4/3}) = 3.
$$
One way of proceeding from here is to notice that if we let $\beta = 2^{2/3}$ then
$$
1+2^{2/3} + 2^{4/3} = 1+\beta+ \beta^2 =\frac{\beta^3-1}{\beta-1}= \frac{3}{\beta-1}
$$
Thus substituting this back into ($\dagger$) we find $a^2 = \beta-1$. But $\beta$ obviously satisfies $g(y)=t^3-4$, hence we deduce that
$$
(a^2+1)^3-4 = 0 \iff a^6+3a^4+3a^2-3=0
$$
Thus $a$ satisfies $f(t)= t^6+3t^4+3t^2-3\in \mathbb Z[t]$. One still needs to check whether this is the minimal polynomial or not of course.